# Trouble with "Assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke" [C#]

Tags: c#, reflection, compilation, runtime, .net-assembly

I have the following problem:
I am compiling C#-code at runtime using the `CSharpCodeProvider` in `Microsoft.CSharp`. The created application runs perfectly, if I double-click on the generated file.

If, however, I am loading my created assembly with `Assembly.Load` and invoking the entrypoint-method with `Assembly.Load("...").EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null)`, I get a *NullReferenceException*.

---

The *NullReferenceException* is referring to the value of the `.EntryPoint`-Property.
When I debug the variable containing the loaded Assembly, VisualStudio shows the following:

[image: Error]

[Larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXzqu.png)

The error is in German and means *The value of "local" or argument "asm" is not available in this instruction pointer and can therefore not be determined. It may have been removed during optimization.*

---

I want to add at this point that my generated assembly is **not** optimized (I also added the compiler argument `/optimize-`, which prevents optimization.)

---

I performed an other test to determine the error source by trying this Code:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

asm.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, argv);
```

This code is also throwing a *NullReferenceException* at the line containing the `Invoke`-call.

---

Does someone here know, where this error is coming from and I can solve it?

Thank you very much :)

---

**EDIT:**

The entrypoint-method is defined as follows:

```
namespace tmp
{
   public static class Program
   {
      [STAThread]
      public static void Main(string[] argv)
      { ... }
   }
}
```

I also tried to invoke it with `.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new string[]{"test", "argument"})`, but it didn't solve the problem :/

**EDIT #2:** I found my error - please look at the comment from [@Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) and myself for the soulution

*~closed~*

Comment: Impossible to guess at when you don't document what the entrypoint method actually looks like.  Your Invoke() call needs to match.  If it is the boilerplate `void Main(string[] args)` then it needs to be asm.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] { "arg1", "arg2", "etc" }});

Comment: Well, that isn't correct.  I gave you the proper Invoke() call, I recommend you use it.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am sorry Sir, I overlooked the `new object[] {}`. The compiler now throws a `TargetInvocationException`, but maybe I can fix this :)

Comment: @HansPassant: I've found my problem: I have to redirect the Console I/O from my reflected method to the "real" console. Thank you very much for your help, Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy and paste from [Hans Passant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616405/trouble-with-assembly-entrypoint-invoke-c#comment45536945_28616405):

```
// Get your assembly.
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

// Get your point of entry.
MethodInfo entryPoint = asm.EntryPoint;

// Invoke point of entry with arguments.
entryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] { "arg1", "arg2", "etc" } } );
```

If you want to access an assembly from an embedded resource, use this snippet:

```
byte[] yourResource = Properties.Resources.YourResourceName;

Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(yourResource);
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you try something like this will it work?

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
MethodInfo myMethod = asm.EntryPoint;
myMethod.Invoke(null, args);
```

assuming that that you know the method you want to invoke

Comment: I just tried this from my end and myMethod is not null... now I must ask
@Unknown6656 where in your code / method are you calling this .. I tried it from my `static void Main(string[] args)`

Comment: I am also calling it from `public static void Main(string[] argv)`, but I found my error. Please see the comments under my question for the solution. Nevertheless, I thank you very much for your help, Sir :)